# server stops creating threads

Tags: c, linux, sockets, pthreads

I have a very simple client-server code. Every time a server receives a packet I create a thread that handles it. The code is shown below. What I can't understand is that after sometime my server stops receiving any data. It just listens and doesn't receive anything. I can't figure out why. Does anyone know the reason.

I'm building my code on Lenovo T470s Fedora 29, Linux user 4.19.15-300.fc29.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jan 14 16:32:35 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Any help is appreciated.

```
/* 
  server.c
  cc -std=gnu11 -pedantic  -lpthread  server.c   -o server.c 
 */

#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUF_SIZE_B 1024

static int fd;

static void *handlePacketThreadWrapper(void *arg);

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t t;
    struct pollfd pollfd;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    uint16_t port = 9500;

    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

    if (fd < 0)
    {
        printf("errno: %d. %s. Failed to create a socket",
                errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    addr.sin_port        = htons(port);

    while(bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("errno: %d. %s. Failed to bind socket. Will attempt again.", errno,
                strerror(errno));
        sleep(1);
    }

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));

    pollfd.fd = fd;
    pollfd.events = POLLIN;

    while(true)
    {

        if (poll(&pollfd, 1, -1) < 0)
        {
            printf("errno: %d. %s", errno, strerror(errno));
        }
        else
        {
            pthread_create(&t, NULL, handlePacketThreadWrapper, NULL);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

static void *handlePacketThreadWrapper(void *arg)
{
    uint8_t buf[BUF_SIZE_B];
    size_t strLen, fullIPLen;
    ssize_t
        i,
        n
        ;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    socklen_t addrLen = sizeof(addr);
    char *str, *fullIP;


    n = recvfrom(fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0,
            (struct sockaddr *)&addr, (socklen_t *)&addrLen);
    if (n < 0)
    {
        printf("errno: %d. %s. Failed to create a socket",
                errno, strerror(errno));
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf("0x%02X ", buf[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

And here is my client code:

```
/* 
  client.c
  cc -std=gnu11 -pedantic  client.c   -o client.c  
 */
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUF_SIZE_B 1024

int main(void)
{
    ssize_t size, i;
    struct sockaddr_in dest;
    int fd;
    char *toIP = "127.0.0.1";
    uint16_t toPort = 9500;
    uint8_t buf[BUF_SIZE_B];

    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        printf("errno: %d, %s", errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&dest, 0, sizeof(dest));
    dest.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    dest.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(toIP);
    dest.sin_port        = htons(toPort);

    while(true)
    {
        size = sendto(fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&dest, sizeof(dest));
        if (size < 0)
        {
            printf("errno: %d. %s. Failed to send bytes to %s:%hu.", 
                    errno, strerror(errno), toIP, toPort);
        }
        else
        {
            for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
                printf("0x%02X ", buf[i]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        usleep(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check the return code from `pthread_create()`.  You don't even know if it works or not.

Comment: "Every time a server receives a packet I create a thread that handles it." <-- this is an extremely inefficient way to handle packets -- the overhead of starting up a new thread (and shutting it down afterwards) is considerable.  Consider using a thread pool instead.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Can you expand on it? I'm not familiar with thread pools

Comment: @flashburn the idea is that instead of spawning a short-lived thread every time you receive a packet, you spawn a single thread (or perhaps a few threads, if you think it's worthwhile) that stick around indefinitely, waiting for work to do.  Then whenever you receive a packet, you add the packet into a mutex-protected queue, and signal one of the threads to wake up, pull the next packet out of the queue, and process it, then go back to sleep again.  In this way you don't have to spawn a new thread every time a packet is received.

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("errno: %d. %s. Failed to create a socket",
                errno, strerror(errno));`  error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  Suggest: `fprintf( stderr, "errno: %d. %s. Failed to create a socket",
                errno, strerror(errno));`

Comment: OT:  regarding: `while(bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)`  if the first call to `bind()` fails, why would you expect a later call to work?

Comment: regarding: `addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    addr.sin_port        = htons(port);
    ....
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));`   after just setting up the struct `addr`, why overwrite it with all 0's?

Comment: OT: all the error message format string(s) should have '\n' as the last character.  Otherwise, the messages will sit in the output buffer until an 'input' is performed or the buffer overflows or the program ends or `fflush( stdout )` is called.

Comment: OT: in the thread function, the statement: `return NULL;` would be much better written as: `pthread_exit( NULL );`

Comment: in the server, in the `main()` function.  before exiting, need to have the statement: `pthread_join( ...., NULL );`  where the `...` is the thread id, as set by the call to `pthread_create()`  This also implies that the variable `t` should actually be an array and the code should track where in that array is the `pthread_t` entry to request a thread to join the main line of the code

Comment: a function, like `sendto()` might not send the whole buffer, so the client code should be checking the returned value and using a sliding window with calls to `sendto()` (with appropriate parameters) in a loop, until the whole buffer is sent

Comment: @JeremyFriesner How does one create a thread pool? What I mean, is that I do know how to create a thread, but how do I create them and wake them up until a packet arrives? I'm genuinely curious. If you could post some code in pastebin, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @flashburn enter c++ thread pool into the search box here, there are dozens of questions on the subject already

Comment: @user3629249 Can you elaborate more on the sliding window idea, I'm not sure I fully understand.

Comment: 'Sliding Window'  example: there are 100 bytes in 'buf' to transmit. the first call to `send()` will have a source address of '&buf[0]' and it returns an indication the 20 bytes actually sent.  So the second call would have a source data address of '&buf[20]' and a length of 'sizeof(buf)-20'.  This loop continues until all 100 bytes are sent.

Answer (score 6):

You can only have as many threads running simultaneously, as `ulimit -u` reports.

Your server never joins the threads, and once the limit is reached it starts failing to create them.

Comment: you must either join the threads after they are finished or detach them so they are freed when they call pthread_exit().

Comment: ...but, as JeremyFriesner states, you would probably be better off using a threadpool than starting and ending a thread for every packet.

Answer (score 0):

In your server the *main* thread and the created thread(s) access the same socket (*fd*) without any protection like exclusive section, so the execution of *poll* and *recvfrom* can be done in any order including *simultaneously*, that probably destruct the internal data of the socket.

You can do for example :

```
while(true)
{

    if (poll(&pollfd, 1, -1) < 0)
    {
        printf("errno: %d. %s", errno, strerror(errno));
    }
    else
    {
        pthread_create(&t, NULL, handlePacketThreadWrapper, NULL);
        pthread_join(&t);
    }
}
```

That both protect the use of the socket and avoid *zombie thread* as mentioned by user58697 in an other answer (the threads are not *detached* by default).

Of course doing that limit the interest to read on the socket in an other thread, but your code is not really compatible with multi threading for several reasons

Comment: How does it destruct internal data of the socket? Can you provide more details on that?

Comment: If I execute `pthread_join` my main thread would be blocked, since it is a blocking call, meaning I won't be able to execute the main thread until created thread finishes.

Comment: Yes the join block the main thread until he other thread finish, this is the goal. Your program is not compatible with the multi threading, there is interest to use an other thread in your case